# Different versions of IE11 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, server, internet-explorer-11

Is anyone familiar with the different versions of IE11 that run on Windows Server 2012? One looks like a normal browser with the URL bar at the top of the screen. The other is a weird, mutant cousin, of IE11 that has the URL bar at the bottom of the page.

When I navigate to About Internet Explorer both of them say version is 11.0.9600.18231, but they obviously look very different. Is there a way to disable or make the weird one look normal?

thanks!

Comment: It seems if I click the wrench symbol in the bottom toolbar, then click "View in the Desktop" I get the correct version of IE. They have 2 different icons. Is there a way to disable the one that appears to run as a Windows App, and just use the one that runs as a regular web browser?

Comment: IE itself is a weird, mutant cousin of all decent browsers!

Answer (score 0):

In "Internet Option" => "Program" tab、"Choose how you open links", select [Always in Internet Explorer on the desktop].
So every link open in Internet Explorer on the desktop (usual IE with he URL bar at the top of the screen).